# Measuring along elevated line using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am trying to measure various lengths along a line which has changing elevation, and splitting the line at the various end points.

I have the lengths that have been taken on along the line (a walking track) but as elevation is constantly changing I have no idea how I am to go about completing this as I haven't been able to find out if measuring along the line will automatically take into account the elevation, or if it will treat it like it is a flat surface which would obviously result in the line being split in the incorrect places.

Comment: If you want to know if the dZ is taken into account add a short line 1m long and set the first point Z to 0, last point Z to 1000 and see if the line is only 1m long or significantly more.. if the line is 1m long Z isn't taken into account in your calculation, otherwise it is.

Comment: I think we need more details about your input data but what you describe sounds to me like calibrating a route in linear referencing: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/linear-referencing/using-arcmap-to-calibrate-routes-with-points.htm